# Python and Shapefile: Very large coordinates after importing shapefile

Tags: python, python-2.7, gis, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap

I downloaded a shapefile of Boston and wants to plot it out using the code below. However it's giving me an error `ValueError: lat_0 must be between -90.000000 and 90.000000 degrees`

Turns out `coords` has values `(33869.92130000144, 777617.2998000011, 330800.31099999696, 959741.1853)` Why is it so large?

[Boston shapefile is obtained here](http://www.mass.gov/anf/research-and-tech/it-serv-and-support/application-serv/office-of-geographic-information-massgis/datalayers/zipcodes.html)

**Code**

```
# Import Boston shapefile
shapefilename = 'ZIPCODES_NT_POLY'
shp = fiona.open(shapefilename + '.shp')
coords = shp.bounds
shp.close()

w, h = coords[2] - coords[0], coords[3] - coords[1]
extra = 0.01

m = Basemap(
    projection='tmerc', ellps='WGS84',
    lon_0 = np.mean([coords[0], coords[2]]), 
    lat_0 = np.mean([coords[1], coords[3]]), 
    llcrnrlon = coords[0] - extra * w,
    llcrnrlat = coords[1] - extra * h,
    urcrnrlon = coords[2] + extra * w,
    urcrnrlat = coords[3] + extra * h,
    resolution = 'i', suppress_ticks = True)
```

**Error**

```
ValueError: lat_0 must be between -90.000000 and 90.000000 degrees
```

Comment: Latitude is an angle which ranges from `0°` at the Equator to `90°` (North or South) at the poles.

Comment: @l'L'l Why does `coords`  have such large values `(33869.92130000144, 777617.2998000011, 330800.31099999696, 959741.1853)`

Comment: Likely because it's coordinates are in sps/spcs and need to be converted into lat/lon.

Comment: @l'L'l It works when I switch to TIGER/Line's shapefiles instead of trying to convert state plane to lat/lon. Thanks!

Comment: Cross-posted to http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/157581

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reproject from the native projection of Eastings and Northings to another coordinate reference system. If you want degrees of Latitude and Longitude, which is usually [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84) or [EPSG:4326](http://epsg.io/4326). Here's how to reproject it:

```
import fiona
import pyproj
from functools import partial
from shapely.geometry import box
from shapely.ops import transform

shp = fiona.open('ZIPCODES_NT_POLY.shp', 'r')
p_in = pyproj.Proj(shp.crs)
bound_box = box(*shp.bounds)
shp.close()

p_out = pyproj.Proj({'init': 'EPSG:4326'})  # aka WGS84
project = partial(pyproj.transform, p_in, p_out)

bound_box_wgs84 = transform(project, bound_box)

print('native box: ' + str(bound_box))
print('WGS84 box: ' + str(bound_box_wgs84))
```

> native box: POLYGON ((330800.310999997 777617.2998000011, 330800.310999997 959741.1853, 33869.92130000144 959741.1853, 33869.92130000144 777617.2998000011, 330800.310999997 777617.2998000011))
>
> WGS84 box: POLYGON ((-69.93980848410942 41.23787282321487, -69.899038698261 42.87724537285449, -73.53324195423785 42.8704709990465, -73.48147096070339 41.2312695091688, -69.93980848410942 41.23787282321487))

Otherwise, most of the parameters that are required by Basemap are in `shp.crs` (take a look).

Answer (score 0):

You must change the coordinate reference system. I recommend `geopandas`:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load zips with the source projection
shapefilename = 'ZIPCODES_NT_POLY'
zips = gpd.read_file(shapefilename + '.shp')
# convert projection to familiar lat/lon
zips = zips.to_crs('epsg:4326')

zips.plot()
plt.show()
```